# AbortedException in Empty Commits of Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm currently developing a Java program using Google Cloud Spanner, utilizing batch inserts within manual transactions via a multithreaded approach. Each thread in the application is responsible for generating and accumulating its own mutation array. As part of the process, we add an insert mutation to the local array and perform empty commits. However, I've encountered an issue where AbortedException arises during these empty commits, and not specifically when the batch size is met for a commit to the database. The transactions are handled using TransactionManager and TransactionContext. I am looking for insights into why this exception occurs specifically at the point of empty commits. Thank you so much!

This is a link to the [repo](https://github.com/kkty39/Spanner-batch-insert/tree/main) of a simplified version of the application.

Basically, the application utilizes a batch processing approach in the SpannerClient class for handling database insert operations. In this process, each thread creates mutations for insert operations, which are stored in a bufferedMutations ArrayList<Mutation>. These mutations are collected until they reach a set batch size. Upon reaching this limit, the batch is sent to the Google Cloud Spanner database in a single transaction.

Some basic errors occur are (more detail printed out when applciation is run locally) two types:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thread-138 in SpannerClient.commit() method- AbortedException occurred.
Current size of mutation buffers array: 94.
Stack Trace:com.google.cloud.spanner.AbortedException: ABORTED: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Database schema has changed



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thread-0 in SpannerClient.commit() method- AbortedException occurred.
Current size of mutation buffers array: 77.
Stack Trace:com.google.cloud.spanner.AbortedException: ABORTED: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Transaction was aborted.
retry_delay {
  nanos: 38655229
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Spanner can abort a read/write transaction for multiple reasons. In the examples given above, one of the aborts was for example caused by a schema change that went into effect during your read/write transaction. But read/write transactions can also be aborted for other reasons, and there is no way to guarantee up front that a given read/write transaction will not be aborted.

It is important to realize that part of the **API contract** for read/write transactions in Cloud Spanner is that **they can always be aborted**. You therefore **always** need to put your read/write transactions in a retry loop. This is also shown in the example for how to use `TransactionManager`:

```java
long singerId = my_singer_id;
try (TransactionManager manager = dbClient.transactionManager()) {
  TransactionContext transaction = manager.begin();
  while (true) {
    String column = "FirstName";
    Struct row = transaction.readRow("Singers", Key.of(singerId), Collections.singleton(column));
    String name = row.getString(column);
    transaction.buffer(Mutation.newUpdateBuilder("Singers").set(column).to(name.toUpperCase()).build());
    try {
      manager.commit();
      break;
    } catch (AbortedException e) {
      Thread.sleep(e.getRetryDelayInMillis());
      transaction = manager.resetForRetry();
    }
  }
}
```

(Source: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/f689f742d8754134523ed0394b9c1b8256adcae2/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClient.java#L429)

Comment: I am always getting two types of erros: retry delays and schema has changed. If reasons for retry_delay error sis unknow, what could possibly caused the `schema has changed` error as I did not make any changes to the dabase schema. Thank you so much Knut.

Comment: `retry_delay` is not an error, it is a hint for how long the application should back off before retrying. See this example: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/4a906bf2719c30dcd7371f497a8a28c250db77be/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClient.java#L442

So the `AbortedException` with a retry_delay is just a 'generic' `AbortedException`. That could be an indication that your transaction conflicted with another transaction.

Comment: The `schema changed` errors indicate that Spanner believes that there was a schema update. Do you have a `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` or something similar in your application that is executed at startup?

But in general: You should not be surprised if Cloud Spanner aborts some of your transactions. That is normal, and the best way to handle it is to back off for the time specified in `retry_delay`, and then retry the transaction.

Comment: One last thing, as this application seems to do a bulk upload: You could also consider using the new BatchWrite feature: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/4a906bf2719c30dcd7371f497a8a28c250db77be/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClient.java#L243

That is however only an option if you can live with the fact that the writes are applied non-atomically, meaning that you need to do a bit of extra handling yourself. But that already seems to be the case in your current application.

Comment: Thank you so much Knut! Your comments are very informative and helpful! Yesterday I figured that in my pom file, I excluded the guava-jdk-5 artifact which is migrated from an old application. After I remove the exclusion, the problems seem to disappear. But I found that the guava dependency is mainly for I/O operations. Do you possibly have some insights for this? I also found that empty commits are taking a long time too.

Comment: OK weird thing.. removing the exclusion does not work when I try it the next day..

Comment: Sorry, I lost track of this thread. Guava should not make any difference for the number of aborted transactions. Removing it is therefore not the reason that you saw a difference. The difference is more likely to have been random.

When you write 'empty commits': Are you sure that these transactions are actually 'empty', in the sense that: A read/write transaction that only reads data and then commits, is 'empty' in the sense that it does not include anything in the Commit RPC. __BUT__ it still needs to verify that all locks are held. So the Commit can still take some time.

Comment: Thank you Knut! Seems that sometimes the commit  would just be aborted out of no reasons and retry is a must have. I appreciate it!